# Getting error after selecting color from "Advanced color option panel" of text color tool in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

5.3 version. In my toolbar for color dialog I want to add more color (Advanced color) option so I `config.colorButton_enableAutomatic = true;` in `config.js` After this I am getting more options. But in more option dialog. But after selecting color it is not showing in selected color area. I am getting `error at line p.getContentElement has 'p' is undefined` in `colordialog.js`

```
function z(a) {
        a = a.data.getTarget();
        var c;
        "td" == a.getName() && (c = a.getChild(0).getHtml()) && (y(),
        f = a,
        f.setAttribute("aria-selected", !0),
        p.getContentElement("picker", "selectedColor").setValue(c))//Getting error
    }
```

I debug but not able to find issue. So my question is:

1. "More color" option will work in ckeditor 4.5.3 version?
2. If I want more "More color" option by changing `config.colorButton_enableAutomatic = true;` will do this for me or I need to do something else also.
3. Any idea to solve error? please help!

[image]